# Get the text of all links

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the text of some `a`, which lives in a li, inside a div. Something like: `div -> ul -> li -> a`. But I not reaching this. I can print the first item and when I change `.find` to `findAll` the console returns a error:

```
"ResultSet object has no attribute `'%s'`. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call `find_all()` when you meant to call `find()`?" 
`% key` AttributeError: `ResultSet` object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call `find_all()` when you meant to call `find()`?
```

My code until now:

```
 1 from urllib.request import urlopen
 2 from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
 3 import pandas as pd
 4 
 5 url = "http://amoraosromances.blogspot.com/"
 6 page = urlopen(url)
 7 soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
 8 
 9 for div in soup.findAll('div', class_='widget Label', id='Label2'):
10     a = div.findAll('a')
11     print(a.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound to `beautifulsoup`, then you can use `Selenium WebDriver` to do the same thing.

I tried this piece of code to get what you wanted

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path  = 'path_to_chromedriver_exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('http://amoraosromances.blogspot.com/')
time.sleep(5)

parent_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#Label2.widget.Label > div > ul')
child_elements = parent_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

for i in child_elements:
    print(i.text)


driver.quit()
```

which gives output like

```
ABANDONADO NO ALTAR (8)
ACIDENTE (97)
ADOLESCENTE (23)
ADORÁVEL PRISIONEIRA FANFIC (1)
ADULTÉRIO (26)
AEROMOÇA (3)
AGENCIA DE CASAMENTO (3)
AMANTE (74)
....
```

You can use this [link](https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/running-script-with-google-chrome/) to get started with Selenium if you want to set it up for Chrome.